# Dynamically adding an array of elements to a UI

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, dynamic

I am trying to add elements to a LinearLayout UI which has already been successfully inflated in a fragment's onCreateView() method.

Below is the onActivityCreated() method where I'm trying to add further elements to the UI.

The UI provides input for a volume calculation, but I do not know at run-time how many dimensions will be required to calculate the volume. The number of dimensions is provided by my VolumeCalculation class depending on the *calcId*.

On debugging, the app crashes in the ***for*** loop as soon as I try to set anything on the *dimHLayouts[dimNumber]* (eg ***dimHLayouts[dimNumber].setId(100 + dimNumber);***). I've tried swapping which attribute I set first. This crash occurs as soon as I try to set an attribute regardless of which attribute I try to set first.

I've also used the ***android.util.Log*** tool and inserted a tonne of Logs to try and see what's going on, but I'm still at a loss since everything up to that point seems to be working as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Get the volume Calculation Type from the bundle passed to this fragment
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    int calcId = bundle.getInt("CalcType");

    // Create a calculation object
    VolumeCalculation calc = new VolumeCalculation(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
    int calcDimensionCount = calc.getCalcDimensionCount(calcId);

    // Get the root LinearLayout of the inflated UI
    LinearLayout inputUILayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout_input);

    // Create array of new LinearLayout objects
    LinearLayout[] dimHLayouts = new LinearLayout[calc.getCalcDimensionCount(calcId)];
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpDimHLayouts = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Create array of new TextView objects
    TextView[] dimTextViews = new TextView[calc.getCalcDimensionCount(calcId)];
    LayoutParams lpDimTextViews = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

    for(int dimNumber=0; dimNumber<calcDimensionCount; dimNumber++) {

        // Setup the horizontal linear layout for the dimension
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].setId(100 + dimNumber);
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].setLayoutParams(lpDimHLayouts);

        // Setup the dimension label TextView
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setId(150 + dimNumber);
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setLayoutParams(lpDimTextViews);
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setText(calc.getDimLabel(calcId, dimNumber));

        // Add TextView to LinearLayout
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].addView(dimTextViews[dimNumber]);

        // To Do: Setup an EditText and add it to the dimension LinearLayout

        // Add dimension LinearLayout to the UI  
        inputUILayout.addView(dimHLayouts[dimNumber]);
    }

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: what is the crash report?

Comment: LogCat says; "thread exiting with uncaught exception"

Comment: yeah, that is what it always says. (that's what she said). A little bit higher, what type of exception, where in code. E.g. http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/tut-images/android-logcat.png --- ClassCastException

Comment: I don't see anything as obvious as a "Caused by:..." comment in my ["LogCat"](http://i.imgur.com/j5iMXUH.png) BTW Thanks for taking the time to looking at my question.

Comment: yeah, you have NullPointerException in your Fragment_Input.java at line 100

Comment: Any thoughts what's causing it?

Comment: what is on your line 100?

Comment: That's the first attempt to set an attribute
dimHLayouts[dimNumber].setId(100 + dimNumber);

Comment: your dimHLayouts is null

Comment: Ahh... ok how do I fix that.. do I need to do something like:
dimHLayouts[dimNumber] = new LinearLayout:  ?? 
Hmm... Just tried my suggetion and Nope.

Comment: test it setting array size to different sizes, i cannot tell where exactly it is wrong in your code

Comment: Thanks _Mocialov Boris_. You've highlighted that I've instantiated but not initialized my dimHLayouts[dimNumber]. Now I need to go and work out how I do that.

Comment: You were spot on Boris. I've added the line;
    dimHLayouts[dimNumber] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
to the start of the code in my **for** loop to initialize each element, and it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to the problem (thanks to the help from Boris Mocialov).

The new UI component arrays were Instantiated, but the individual elements of the arrays were not Initialized.

I've changed the ***for*** loop as shown below, to Initialize each element eg `dimHLayouts[dimNumber] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());` It now works fine.

```
    for(int dimNumber=0; dimNumber<calcDimensionCount; dimNumber++) {

        // Setup the horizontal linear layout for the dimension
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].setLayoutParams(lpDimHLayouts);

        // Setup the dimension label TextView
        dimTextViews[dimNumber] = new TextView(getActivity());
        textViewIds[dimNumber] = generateViewId();
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setId(textViewIds[dimNumber]);
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setLayoutParams(lpDimTextViews);
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
        dimTextViews[dimNumber].setText(calc.getDimLabel(calcId, dimNumber));

        // Setup the dimension label EditText
        dimEditTexts[dimNumber] = new EditText(getActivity());
        editTextIds[dimNumber] = generateViewId();
        dimEditTexts[dimNumber].setId(editTextIds[dimNumber]);
        dimEditTexts[dimNumber].setLayoutParams(lpDimEditTexts);
        dimEditTexts[dimNumber].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        dimEditTexts[dimNumber].setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMediumInverse);


        // Add TextView and EditText to LinearLayout
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].addView(dimTextViews[dimNumber]);
        dimHLayouts[dimNumber].addView(dimEditTexts[dimNumber]);


        // Add dimension LinearLayout to the UI  
        inputUILayout.addView(dimHLayouts[dimNumber]);
    }
```

Does anybody know, are there more efficient and elegant ways to dynamically add a number of elements which is unknown at run time?